# Matlab RandomForest prediction error calculation

Tags: matlab, random-forest

I am using Random Forests in Matlab for regression. After educating my model on train data, I want to get MSE on test data not used in training. I do that two ways:

1. call `predict` and directly calculate MSE using predicted and actual values
2. call `error` and use built in TreeBagger functionality to do the same task.

In first case I get 10 times bigger result. Why? The only explanation I have, is that built in function somehow discounts outliers in prediction, but I am not sure how exactly it is done.

Can somebody, please, explain all this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use predict on a train set, the result will be highly overfitted and meaningless -- this actually applies to all ML algorithms, and this is why test sets, cross-validations and similar stuff is used.

However, one of the big advantages of bagging is that it can produce an approximation of error on train set as it would be a test -- this is called out-of-bag (OOB) and those predictions (available in `OOBPred`) are used by Matlab in `error` to produce "true" error.

Comment: I am using predict on test set. It's written in my question. From Matlab help: "err = error(B,X,Y)  computes mean squared error (MSE) for regression trees for each tree, for predictors X given true response Y." What you are talking about is (again Matlab reference quote):"err = oobError(B) computes mean squared error (for regression trees) for out-of-bag observations in the training data".

Comment: Okay, it's really shamefull but I must admit that difference between Matlab built in function and my direct calculations appeared due to two factors: 1) typo in my MSE formula, 2) setting mode 'individual' in error command and getting array of errors per tree in forest, instead of total error. I will accept mbq's answer because actually his comment lead me to check TreeBagger's options one more time and find my mistakes.